# Select tag & options for select 101

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, model, ruby-on-rails-4, form-helpers

Can someone explain me how this exactly works ?

**Problem:**

I have a Scaffold and run the migration:

```
rails g migration AddRarityToTags rarity:string
```

For the rarity input i need a dropdown displaying a list of options to select from.

```
e.g. Rarity = Free
              Common
              Rare
              Epic
```

If i'm right i need something like this:

```
  select_tag :rarity, options_for_select(@rarity)
```

I searched a lot but it didn't helped much, i got more confused.

Can someone help me out ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine putting the raw options into the tag as a string:

```
select_tag :rarity, '<option>Free</option><option>Common</option>...'
```

That's what `options_for_select` returns, if you pass in an array:

```
select_tag :rarity, options_for_select(['Free', 'Common', ...])
```

See: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select

To enforce the "dumb views" rule, and to let others use that array, you can move it to the model:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base

  RARITY_LEVELS = %w(Free Common Rare Epic)

end
```

...

```
select_tag :rarity, options_for_select(Tag::RARITY_LEVELS)
```

Both me and the OP would like to know if Rails, or any gems, let us get any DRYer than this; if, for example, Rails lets us attach the `RARITY_LEVELS` directly to the `rarity` field...

Comment: Hey Phil, thanks for answering. Saw that and it's kinda working if i hard code it like that.. But isn't there a method (i thinks it's from the model or something) where i can call the options ?

Comment: You can put the array as a constant in your model. I was looking for the feature you want, because it sounds very DRY to attach those constants directly to your model's field. But nobody needs them except your own logic, and your `options_for_select` call, so attach them to whatever you like, then pass them into that call!

Comment: Cool, that sound really ok... Could you update your Answer with the steps ?? (Newbie here) :)